# XSLT Performance Help for High Volume Data Set

Tags: performance, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I'm running an XSLT to transform a very high volume XML input (multiple millions of lines) and trying to make the transformation more efficient.

My input data looks something like this:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <groupID>123</groupID>
        <primary>true</primary>
        <date>2023-01-31</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>ABC</ID>
           <ID type='objID'>0110</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>123</groupID>
        <primary>true</primary>
        <date>2023-01-31</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>ABC</ID>
           <ID type='objID'>0110</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>123</groupID>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <date>2023-01-31</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>XYZ</ID>
           <ID type='objID'>0221</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>789</groupID>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <date>2023-01-01</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>087</ID>
           <ID type='objID'>0330</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>789</groupID>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <date>2023-01-01</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>087</ID>
           <ID type='objID'>0330</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
</root>
```

I want to update the lineID to match against the primary lineID within the same group and copy over all the XML.
So the output would look like this.

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <groupID>123</groupID>
        <primary>true</primary>
        <date>2023-01-31</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>ABC</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>123</groupID>
        <primary>true</primary>
        <date>2023-01-31</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>ABC</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>123</groupID>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <date>2023-01-31</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>ABC</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>789</groupID>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <date>2023-01-01</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>087</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <groupID>789</groupID>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <date>2023-01-01</date>
        <lineID>
           <ID type='index'>087</ID>
        </lineID>
    </entry>
</root>
```

This is my xslt and it is working, but it's a bit slow. I just can't figure our how to write a more efficient one. Any pointers, suggestions, or edits appreciated! I know the exists() function is not particularly efficient and I've considered going to 3.0, but I couldn't get the stream-able mode or input doc to work correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match='lineID'>
        <xsl:variable name='ID' select='.'/>
        <xsl:variable name='groupID' select='../groupID'/>
        
        <lineID>            
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test='exists(../../entry[groupID = $groupID and primary = true() and lineID != $ID])'>
                        <xsl:value-of select='../../entry[groupID = $groupID and primary = true() and lineID != $ID][1]/lineID'/>
                    </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select='$ID'/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </lineID>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea of using streaming with group-adjacent; given that the values of the `entry` elements are in child elements you will need to use `copy-of()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="entry!copy-of()" group-adjacent="groupID">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="grounded">
          <xsl:with-param name="lineID" tunnel="yes" select="current-group()[primary = 'true'][1]/lineID"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="grounded" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="lineID" mode="grounded">
    <xsl:param name="lineID" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:copy>{($lineID, .)[1]}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An accumulator alone will not help in my view if I understand your data right as it is not clear at which position (at all) your "primary" lineID occurs.

Comment: This approach seems to be working well, but one hick up. I've found some records that have a different format for the lineID. I've updated the source XML, how would that change this template? And correct - the "primary" lineID can occur anywhere within the group.

Comment: For the changed input/output, if you want to only copy the `ID[@type = 'index']`, use e.g. `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="($lineID, .)[1]/ID[@type = 'index']"/></xsl:copy>` instead of e.g. `<xsl:copy>{($lineID, .)[1]}</xsl:copy>`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way to improve performance would be to use an XSLT processor that does join optimization for expressions like `//entry[groupID = $groupID]`. For example (my company's product, sorry) Saxon-EE. Another way would be to optimise it "by hand" using keys: declare a key with `match="entry" use="groupID"` and use the key() function to access it. This would change the code from being quadratic in the data size to being effectively linear (technically O(n log n)).

If the groups are adjacent, as in your example, then you can exploit this by not searching the whole document for entries with a matching groupID, but only searching backwards until you find a non-matching one. The most effective way of doing that would be to process each group separately using `xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent`; alternatively in XSLT 3.0 use `xsl:iterate` setting parameter to the groupID and lineID of the current group.

A streaming solution using XSLT 3.0 is certainly possible, though a bit more difficult to write. As @ConalTuohy suggests, this could be done using accumulators, but I would probably do it using `xsl:iterate`. Streaming will save you a lot of memory, but if you're not short of memory then it won't necessarily be much faster.

The one big thing to address is the quadratic inefficiency of the `../../entry[groupID = $groupID]` search.

Answer (score 1):

The inefficiency here is not in the use of the `exists()` function but in the XPath expressions such as `../../entry[groupID = $groupID and primary = true() and lineID != $ID]` which must look at every `entry` in the document and evaluate the predicate.

You could certainly improve performance here, e.g. by using `for-each-group` to group the `entry` elements by `groupID`, or using an `xsl:key` to speed up access to the first `entry` with a given `groupID`, or something. It's not clear from your description whether the `entry` elements are sorted by `groupID`, which is a relevant detail.

But really in a scenario such as you describe, with multiple millions of records, I think you'd be well advised to make the switch to XSLT 3.0 and use streaming if you can, and use an accumulator to keep a record of the current `lineID`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#accumulators